# Flex positioning of sidebar when in particular order

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple 2-column layout with 3 sections. Depending on a media query, I want to change the order of them - for this I am using flex `order`.

This works fine, except I get my narrow sidebar section starting at the end of the first section, or similar to this. Is there a way I can get them to position more like jigsaw pieces?

Fiddle example of issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/an7m3yvs/

HTML:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
      BOX 1
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
      BOX 2
    </div>

    <div class="box3">
      BOX 3 Sidebar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page-wrapper{
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
 
}
.container{
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.box1{
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  width:70%;
  height:400px;
  order:1;
}
.box2{
  display:inline-block;
  background:green;
  width:70%;
  height:150px;
  order:2;
}
.box3{
  display:inline-block;
  background:grey;
  width:30%;
  height:600px;
  order:3;
}
```

How I want it:

[image: How I want it]

(I know this can be done simpler but the idea is so I can change the order with a media query, as in mobile I want a single column and them in a different order.)

GRID ATTEMPT: https://jsfiddle.net/w489b2fj/

Comment: To me, that sounds like a job for CSS Grid.

Comment: @davidgiesemann could you give an example of this in grid where in mobile it would place box3 inbetween box 1 and 2?

Comment: sure, have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd element is not positioned according to the first element but to its predecessor. The sidebar will occupy the remaining space after the 2nd element and not the 1st.

To achieve the desired result, I think it is better to manage 2 flexbox containers. The first includes box1 and box2. The second includes box container and the sidebar.

Edit HTML:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="box1">
          BOX 1
        </div>
        <div class="box2">
          BOX 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
      BOX 3 Sidebar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And edit the CSS:

```
.container, .content-wrapper{
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.content-wrapper {
    width: 70%;
}

.box1, .box2 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, with this new information I have another solution:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.box3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank-you but the issue is I would want BOX 3 sidebar, to be in the middle on mobile layout. So this wouldn't work, as I can only position it above, or below Box 1 + 2.

Comment: I modified my answer with a new solution at the end. There is only the CSS to modify.

Comment: After using this I've realised this presents a new problem. Because of the absolute positioning, the container can't wrap it, so the sidebar box3, if bigger, overlaps elements below.

Comment: @davidgiesemann's solution is arguably better then. I can not comment under his post. If I understood the problem correctly, to solve it you have to replace the 2nd value of grid-template-rows. See: https://jsfiddle.net/tnph5sjL/

Comment: This looks correct Armand, can you explain for me how `grid-template-rows: minmax(0, auto) minmax(0, 1fr);` works? I don't really understand what magic is happening here. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm still new to CSS grid, so I'm not sure I understand why auto prevents the container to wrap the boxes...  
grid-template-rows property defines the size of the rows. Here we have two rows so two values. minmax defines a size interval between min and max. The fr unit represents a fraction of the space available in the grid container, so 1fr represents all of the remaining space.  
1st row: the minimum size is 0 and the maximum size (auto) depends on the content.
2nd row: the minimum size is 0 and its maximum size must match the size of the space available in the container (therefore 1fr).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by adding `flex-direction: column;` to the container. But in this case (in order to wrap the items) you also need to set a fixed `height`, in your case `height: 550px;`.

And actually, you don't need the `order` settings for the flex items in this simple case...

```css
.page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 550px;
}

.box1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 70%;
  height: 400px;
  order: 1;
}

.box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  width: 70%;
  height: 150px;
  order: 2;
}

.box3 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: grey;
  width: 30%;
  height: 600px;
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
      BOX 1
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
      BOX 2
    </div>

    <div class="box3">
      BOX 3 Sidebar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks but I don't know the final height of the page, so wouldn't be able to implement it. As I've mentioned in other comments, I need Box 3 to go inbetween 1 and 2 when in mobile, so grouping these like the other answers, would not work either.

Answer (score 1):

You wanted an answer using CSS Grid, where box3 places inbetween box1 and box2 in mobile viewports. Here you are:

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "box1"
  "box3"
  "box2"
}

@media (min-width:768px){
  .container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
    "box1 box3"
    "box2 box3"
  }
}

.box1{
  grid-area: box1;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.box2{
  grid-area: box2;
  background-color: #0f0;
}

.box3{
  grid-area: box3;
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
      BOX 1
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
      BOX 2
    </div>

    <div class="box3">
      BOX 3 Sidebar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank-you David, I feel I am almost there using a grid solution instead. However I've got an issue where the boxes in desktop don't push up. I've edited my post with a "GRID ATTEMPT" fiddle for you to see. I need BOX 1 to start underneath BOX 2 without the gap inbetween, I've got it working fine in mobile with a few tweaks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qdtzr69k/ have a look at this one.

Comment: Okay, so we are nearly there, thanks for your help with this (grids isn't my strong point hence starting with flex). This solves that issue but the container doesn't wrap the boxes: https://jsfiddle.net/xaeLj096/ I can only do this by taking out the grid-template-rows:minmax... but this reverts it back to before.

Comment: @nicksource I am not sure I understood, but what about this one: 

https://jsfiddle.net/58zmgtpj/

Answer (score 0):

Try using position property and place the boxes relative to page wrapper.

Comment: did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

if you can change HTML ( and always make good structure ) try this:
do the flex on c1 and c2 elements and you simply remove all inline-block instructions

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
  <div class=c1>
    <div class="box1">
      BOX 1
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
      BOX 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=c2>
    <div class="box3">
      BOX 3 Sidebar
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.page-wrapper{
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
 
}
.container{
 display:flex;
}
.box1{
  background:red;
  height:200px;
  order:2;
}
.box2{
  background:green;
  height:150px;
  order:1;
}
.box3{

  background:grey;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
}
.c2{
  
  width:30%;
  flex-basis:1;
}
.c1{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:70%;
  flex-basis:1;
}
```

Comment: Thank-you but the issue is I would want BOX 3 sidebar, to be in the middle on mobile layout. So this wouldn't work, as I can only position it above, or below Box 1 + 2.